# How can I view my Google Contacts groups with my Samsung Fascinate?

Tags: contacts, contact-groups

My phone's contacts sync with my Google Contacts, but they are all in the same group (called "Google"). I would like for the sub-groups that I have created in Google Contacts to be accessible from my phone, so I can view/organize my contacts by these groups. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean have the groups themselves (for organizational purposes) or just the contacts within the groups accessible?

Comment: I mean the groups themselves (for organizational purposes). See my comment on Bryan's answer.

Comment: I have edited the question slightly to reflect the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Groups tab in the contacts app shows the individual Google contacts groups, including the built-in ones ("Coworkers" etc.) and my custom groups, and they are browsable.  This is on my Galaxy S Vibrant running 2.2, with TouchWiz.

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait for 2.2 then--they definitely don't show up on my fascinate running 2.1.

Comment: The SGS phones are nearly impossible to brick and easy to revert to stock for warranty purposes, if you want to consider a custom ROM.

Comment: It sounds like 2.2 is coming out in a few weeks. If I'm not happy with it, or it gets delayed again, then I'll consider rooting. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: 2.2 is out, and this solution now works!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Contacts. Hit menu --> Display options. Under "Choose contacts to display" tap the account (gmail) and then check the groups you want.

Comment: This controls which of my Google Contacts groups are displayed in my list of contacts, but they are still only considered part of the single group "Google". I want to organize my contacts by Google Contacts group.

Comment: @Matthew what do you mean by "organize" do you want to sort them in the order of the group they're in? Or something else?

Comment: @GAThrawn: Browse by group and send message to group would be the two biggest things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it specifically in TouchWiz, but on my Droid I had to install [Groupy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/groupy-contact-by-group/com.kigate.groupy) to accomplish this.  It works but be careful and test it out first as if you add groups and sync in the wrong order you'll end up with tons of duplicates.